# Multiple Autocomplete Material UI filterSelectedOptions not working at first search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Even when I use filterSelectedOptions prop in my utocomplete, it only works when there's a pre defined chip used: [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAtQB.png)

but when is a brand new typed option, it duplicates it multiple times:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qtjj.png)

I'm trying to used filterOptions, but it's not working and i don't hace clear how to do it :(
this is my current code:

```
 const handleAutocomplete = (e, valueTags) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tagIdsArray = [];
    valueTags.forEach((valueTag) => {
      tagIdsArray.push(Number(tags.filter(tag => valueTag.title === tag.title).shift().id));
    });
    const tagIds = [...new Set(tagIdsArray)];
    handleTag(tagIds);
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      options={tags}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      defaultValue={tagDafaultIds}
      filterSelectedOptions
      onChange={handleAutocomplete}
      // filterOptions={(options) => {
      //   options.filter(option => option.title);
      //   return options;
      // }}
      // filterOptions={(options) => {
      //   const tagsOptions = [...new Set(options)];
      //   return tagsOptions;
      // }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Tags"
          placeholder="Select multiple tags"
          margin="normal"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**If any one has the same trouble, I corrected it using the prop VALUE of MUI instead of default Value.**